# Regex ignore one word between tags

Tags: java, regex

how can i ignore one word between two tags?

For example i have text like

[b]some text text some text some [b] text some text [/b]

I would like to match everything between [b] and [/b] but ignore [b] between them.

Comment: I am 100% sure there are mega tons of examples out there

Comment: Will the text always have ` [b]` at the start and `[\b]` at the end?

Comment: Well it might look like this:    Some text some text [b] some text some text [b] some text [/b] some text

Comment: This is why CFGs should not be parsed with Regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
(\[b\])[\w\s\[\]]*(\[/b\])
```

This starts at any [b] and goes on to the next [/b], resulting in

```
some text text some text some [b] text some text
```

Comment: But it does not ignore [b] inside

Comment: It does. If you wish to remove it from the string use .replaceAll("[b]", "") afterwards

Comment: I know i can do it like that but i want to just ignore it with regex. I have already regex which works like yours          \[b].*?\[/b]